# How to set the state for element after it mounted in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app with the following code. In my user data form, a notification message will be shown after submitting the for. Notification message can be either a success message or a fail message. Fail message may have several types of errors. I'm checking the type of the error and set the message as the type. The problem is, since the notification message is not displayed until click on submit button, console says "**`Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component`**". How can I solve this?

Component:

```
class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      successMsg: null,
      failMsg: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    document.getElementById("userSuccess").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("userFail").style.display = "none";
  }

  sendData=()=>{
     //call AXIOS and call createSuccessMsg() in 'then' & call createFailMsg(errorMsg) in 'catch'
  }

  createSuccessMsg() {
    document.getElementById("userSuccess").style.display = "flex";
    this.setState({ successMsg: 'Successfully created!' });
  }

  createFailMsg(errorMsg) {
    document.getElementById("userFail").style.display = "flex";
    if ((typeof errorMsg) === "object") {
      if (errorMsg.email) {
        this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg.email });
      }
      if (errorMsg.role) {
        this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg.role });
      }
      else{
        this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg });
      }
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div id="userSuccess">{this.state.successMsg}</div>
        <div id="userFail">{this.state.failMsg}</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.sendData}>
          //Inputs
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you call `createFailMsg` ?

Comment: Just FYI. Setting `id`s and doing `.getElementById` is a bad convention in React. You should only manipulate React component. Not DOM elements

Comment: @JonasWilms He does it in the `catch` of the axios call.

Comment: And where do you call `sendData`?

Comment: @JonasWilms in `form onSubmit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check before for _isMounted:

```
class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      successMsg: null,
      failMsg: null
    };
    this._isMounted = false;
}

componentDidMount(){ this._isMounted = true; }


componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}
  componentDidMount(){
    document.getElementById("userSuccess").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("userFail").style.display = "none";
  }

  sendData=()=>{
     //call AXIOS and call createSuccessMsg() in 'then' & call createFailMsg(errorMsg) in 'catch'
  }

  createSuccessMsg() {
    document.getElementById("userSuccess").style.display = "flex";
    this._isMounted &&  this.setState({ successMsg: 'Successfully created!' });
  }

  createFailMsg(errorMsg) {
    document.getElementById("userFail").style.display = "flex";
    if ((typeof errorMsg) === "object") {
      if (errorMsg.email) {
        this._isMounted && this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg.email });
      }
      if (errorMsg.role) {
        this._isMounted && this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg.role });
      }
      else{
        this._isMounted && this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg });
      }
    }
    else {
      this._isMounted && this.setState({ failMsg: errorMsg });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div id="userSuccess">{this.state.successMsg}</div>
        <div id="userFail">{this.state.failMsg}</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.sendData}>
          //Inputs
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related with page reload after submitting the form. You have to `e.preventDefault()` inside `this.sendData`. Not sure, just came into my mind at first look.